# R Studio 'rworldmap' package installation errors for dashDB

Tags: db2, rstudio, ibm-cloud, rworldmap, dashdb

**Background:** I am creating an app on IBM Bluemix which involves using DashDB. From there I opened R Studio.

I am new to R, and I am trying to install **rworldmap** on R Studio. While installing the same i checked the **Install Dependencies** button. The installation failed and gave some errors during the **spam** package installation.

The installer then tries to install the below dependencies (packages):

- spam
- fields

**spam** package Installation Warnings/Error Logs:

```
installing to /mnt/blumeta0/home/dash014837/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/spam/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in setOldClass(c("dist", "numeric")) : 
inconsistent old-style class information for “dist”; the class is defined but does not extend “numeric” and is not valid as the data part
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘spam’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘spam’
* removing ‘/mnt/blumeta0/home/dash014837/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/spam’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘spam’ had non-zero exit status
```

**fields** package installation Warnings/Errors log:

```
Attaching package: ‘arules’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

%in%, write

ERROR: dependency ‘spam’ is not available for package ‘fields’
* removing ‘/mnt/blumeta0/home/dash014837/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/fields’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘fields’ had non-zero exit status
```

**rworldmaps** package Warnings/Errors log:

```
The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

%in%, write

ERROR: dependency ‘fields’ is not available for package ‘rworldmap’
* removing ‘/mnt/blumeta0/home/dash014837/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rworldmap’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rworldmap’ had non-zero exit status
```

Please help me with resolving the issue.

Comment: What was the syntax you used to install the package?

Comment: On the web-console, you can do by firing the install.package() command or by providing it the tar/zip file. I tired both the ways and it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this problem. The development team has been made aware that certain per-requisite packages are not installed on the system and a solution is being worked on. When the problem has been resolved, we will update you to try again.